# Image Loader can't retrieve the image from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to retrieve image from firebase by code

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                imageLoader.displayImage(
                        singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).`getProfile_photo()`,
                        holder.profileImage);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: query cancelled.");
        }
    });
```

Where in UserAccountSettings class

```
 public String getProfile_photo() {
    return profile_photo;
}

public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
}
```

Now it does not retrieves any image, I tried to write a toast message to check if `onDataChange` is being called, but still there is no toast appearing at all.
Please give me idea to retrieve it correctly.

Comment: please show the database

Comment: Debug your code first make sure you are getting the image url or not !

Comment: Please add you database structure and your model class.